# Call method in jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, delayed-execution

I've downloaded [The Schedule Template](https://codyhouse.co/gem/schedule-template/) from Codyhouse - it's a jQuery plugin (and CSS) that creates a Calendar Schedule on a `div`.

The jQuery plugin autoruns since all code in the .js file (`main.js`)  is placed in the `document.ready` function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
..
..  function SchedulePlan( element ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.timeline = this.element.find('.timeline');
..
..
}
```

The problem is that the `div` element I'm trying to apply the Schedule template to isn't created (dynamically created via JavaScript) when `document.ready` fires.

Is there some way to call the `SchedulePlan` function from JavaScript, after the `div` is created?

`#calendarDetail` is the `div`. I've tried a few syntaxes, such as:

```
$("#calendarDetail").SchedulePlan($('#calendarDetail'));
```

and

```
$().SchedulePlan($('#calendarDetail'));
```

But I get this error:

> SchedulePlan is undefined

Is there any way to call this method?

Comment: Yes, u can do it with DOMNodeInserted

Comment: Can you call `SchedulePlan` from the same JavaScript that creates the div, or does it have to be called separately?

Comment: It sounds like your issue is with the plugin being loaded or attached, not with that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plug in does not expose a method for doing this, so I would suggest to delay the loading of the plug in until you have all your elements with the `cd-schedule` class loaded in the DOM.

So remove the `<script src="main.js"></script>` element you have, and instead add this code at the right place, so it executes at the appropriate time:

```
$.getScript("main.js");
```

Comment: Is seems to solve the problem, thank you - have to check if it works if I call it multiple times on same page (if user clicks "show" calendar multiple times)